# TYPO3: jQuery Smooth Page Scrolling

Tags: typo3-7.6.x

I have coolURI installed and use the following code.

Root template:

```
config {
    baseURL = http://www.my-domain.org/
    tx_cooluri_enable = 1
    redirectOldLinksToNew = 1
    simulateStaticDocuments = 0
    prefixLocalAnchors = all
}
```

The fading is fine. But the cursor always jumps to the top of the root page  because the generated link is the same for every page

```
http://www.my-domain.org/#
```

What can I do to get the correct paths in my URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use baseURL **every** URL is based on it, even local anchor URLs like '#'.

Either you change your template and insert the URL of the current page
or you avoid baseurl as recommended and use 'config.**absRefPrefix**' instead.